# Calling QGraphicsLineItem::boundingRect inside QGraphicsLineItem::shape causes a crash

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qgraphicslineitem

I am trying to create a drawing application using Qt.

When selecting a shape, I found that the selection range was too limited to the shape, making it difficult to select. Therefore, I overloaded the `shape()` method of `QGraphicsLineItem`.

Strangely, as soon as I called the `boundingRect()` method within `shape()`, the program immediately crashed:

```cpp
QPainterPath CLineItem::shape() const
{
    qreal radius = 1.0;

    QPainterPath path;
    path.moveTo(this->line().p1());
    path.lineTo(this->line().p2());

    qDebug() << "test1" << Qt::endl;
    this->boundingRect();
    qDebug() << "test2" << Qt::endl;

    //path.addRect(this->boundingRect().adjusted(-radius, -radius, radius, radius));
    return path;
}
```

It only outputs "test1", without "test2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the documentation says that, by default, `shape()` calls `boundingRect()`, most basic QGraphicsItems (including QGraphicsLineItem) actually do the opposite: `boundingRect()` calls `shape()`, which will construct a path based on the shape (possibly considering the pen width) and finally returns its [`controlPointsRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#controlPointRect).

Since you're calling the default `boundingRect()`, it will attempt to call your `shape()` override, causing recursion.

If you want to get a valid path with an increased selection area, then you have two options:

- add a QRectF created with the two points of the line, and eventually adjust it considering both the pen width and your radius;
- use QPainterPathStroker, using a pen width equal to the radius, and call its `createStroke()` with the `path` you initially created using the two points of the line;

I would suggest the second option, because `shape()` is used for collision detection (including mouse event handling) and using the full bounding rect is not a good choice for a line.

Comment: You're right for QGraphicsLineItem but for the rest - can you please show where boundingRect() is calling shape() ? I could not find an example and the default implementation is doing this:
`QPainterPath QGraphicsItem::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(boundingRect());
    return path;
}
`

Comment: @chehrlic See the sources of [qgraphicsitem.cpp](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp): other than QGraphicsLineItem, `boundingRect()` is also overridden by QGraphicsPathItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem and QGraphicsPolygonItem, using `shape()` whenever they have a valid pen set with width greater than 0. The only exception to basic shapes is QGraphicsRectItem (for obvious reasons).